# ggsave error: cannot find function "dev"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get the following error when trying to save my ggplot:

```
Error in ggsave(paste0(projDir, "figs/lmGtaGridCombined.png")) : 
  could not find function "dev"
```

This was code that worked earlier this year, before the newest ggplot(2.0.0).  The 3rd party code I'm using (https://rpubs.com/Koundy/71792;  which uses ggthemes) worked great earlier this year to make my images more publication-friendly.  However, now the ggthemes code gave errors related to:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Theme element 'text' has NULL property: margin, debug
In addition: Warning message:
`axis.ticks.margin` is deprecated. Please set `margin` property  of `axis.text` instead 
>
```

which I thought I fixed by changing this line:

```
 text = element_text()
```

to  this:

```
text = element_text(margin=margin(), debug= F),
```

which made a version of my image print, but many aspects (ie, x-label spacing flush instead of offset) not right.  Plus-  ggsave gave the above error, which is now my biggest problem, as I am considering manually fixing the image if I can just get it to print similarly to as it did before.

I've tried png ..... dev.off  but I can't get it to print in the right dimensions and resolution as it did originally with ggsave.

Please help.  I've been scared to post on stackoverflow up until now, but I'm very desperate.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your [`ggthemes`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggthemes/index.html) package: `install.packages("ggthemes")`. Then, it should work.

Comment: I updated ggthemes-  but that didn't change my error.  Thanks for the suggestions- any other idea?  I'm happy to post more of the code (as ugly as it is) in case that's helpful

Comment: I do realize that these are two issues (ggsave failing and the deprecated elements of the ggtheme script) probably but in case they were both related to the newer version of ggplot2.  Thanks again for anyone who has any suggestions.

Comment: UPDATE: I ran update.packages() and after that, everything seems to work again! Wish i knew exactly what went wrong, but so relieved that I can edit my images once more.  Thanks, @lukeA as that started the process of updating everything.